# Деструктор C++ уничтожает объекты класса раньше, чем нужно

Tags: классы, c++, перегрузка-операторов

Добрый день!

Нужно создать класс (строка, завершающаяся терминальным нулём) и перегрузить операции «+» (конкатенация строк) и «[]» (вставка символа). С этими задачами я справился без труда, и пришло время заняться созданием деструктора. И тут понеслось...

Суть в том, что когда начинает работать процедура перегрузки операции «+», у меня создаётся дополнительная переменная *k*, в которую копируется первая строка, а затем при помощи `strcat` добавляется вторая. И, казалось бы, всё хорошо, но как только дело доходит до `return`, деструктор подчищает переменную *k* и возвращает... ну, возвращает всякую ерунду.

Не то чтобы я удивлён этим событием, я прекрасно понимаю, почему это происходит, но никак не могу решить эту проблему. Подскажите, как я могу исправить этот косяк.

Собственно говоря, код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

class stroka
{
private:
    char* s;
    int n;

public:
    stroka();       //Конструктор по умолчанию
    stroka(int n1); //Конструктор с параметром
    void input();   //Функция ввода строки
    void output();  //Функция вывода строки на экран

    friend stroka& operator + (stroka& A, stroka& B);

    char& operator [] (int p)
    {
        return s[p];
    }

    ~stroka(void);
};

stroka::~stroka(void)
{
    std::cout << "Очистка памяти" << std::endl;
    delete[] s;
}

stroka::stroka()
{
    s = new char[1];
    *s = 0;
    n = 0;
}

stroka::stroka(int n1)
{
    s = new char[n1];
    n = n1;
}

void stroka::input()
{
    std::cout << "Введите строку: ";
    std::cin.getline(s, n, '\n');
}

void stroka::output()
{
    std::cout << "Введённая строка: " << s << std::endl << std::endl;
}

stroka& operator + (stroka& A, stroka& B)
{
    stroka k(A.n + B.n);
    strcpy(k.s, A.s);   //Копируем 1-ую строку в новую
    strcat(k.s, B.s);   //Вставляем 2-ую строку в конец новой
    return k;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(0, "Rus");

    stroka A(10);
    stroka B(10);


    A.input();  //Ввод строки
    A.output(); //Вывод строки

    B.input();
    B.output();

    stroka C = A + B;
    C.output();


    int pos;    //Позиция вставки
    std::cout << "Номер позиции вставки элемента: ";
    std::cin >> pos;

    std::cout << "Введите элемент: ";
    char symbol;    //Вставляемый символ
    std::cin >> symbol;

    C[pos] = symbol;
    C.output();


    std::cout << endl << "Хорошего дня!";
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для начала, у вас неправильный оператор сложения. Он возвращает *ссылку* на экземпляр класса в стеке. Это плохо, потому что по выходу из функции его стек умирает. Переделайте функцию, чтобы она возвращала не ссылку, а копию объекта.

Далее, вам понадобится конструктор копирования (знаете, что это такое?). Дело в том, что при возвращении класса из функции локальная переменная копируется в результат при помощи этого самого конструктора. Поскольку у вас конструктор не определён, используется конструктор по умолчанию, который копирует все поля, в частности, "мёртвый" указатель.

Итого:

```
stroka operator + (const stroka& A, const stroka& B);
stroka(const stroka& A);
```

Кстати, правило «[большой тройки](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)» рекомендует сделать деструктор виртуальным, и добавить оператор присваивания.

Comment: Ну вы меня прям загрузили, я за вами не успеваю гуглить. Давайте по порядку:

1) Насчёт первого замечания: ну тут вроде я всё понял, даже не знаю, зачем я впихнул ссылку.

Comment: 2) Копирующий конструктор - это наверно пока единственный пункт, который я не понял. Вы написали: "Дело в том, что при возвращении класса из функции локальная переменная копируется в результат при помощи этого самого конструктора" - речь идёт как раз о return k ? 

Я не совсем понял где вызывается конструктор по умолчанию, о котором вы говорите. Я же уже вызывал конструктор с параметрами: 

stroka k(A.n+B.n)

...и теперь мне просто нужно вернуть k обратно в main. Как и где тут должен отработать копирующий конструктор?

Comment: 3) Я читал про виртуальный деструктор и он, вроде как, нужен, если используются производный класс, у меня же его нет. Ну в любом случае, это что-то типо этого:?

virtual ~stroka(void);

Comment: 2) Копирующий конструктор вызывается неявно строкой `return k`: объект `k` копируется в возвращаемое значение функции.

3) В принципе, вы правы: в данном примере виртуальность деструктора необязательна. Это скорее хороший тон, ну и на случай, если вы всё же унаследуетесь от этого класса. Достаточно просто написать `virtual`, да.

Comment: Так-так-так, кажется что-то получается, правда кривовато, но всё же. Я написал копирующий конструктор:

stroka::stroka(const stroka& A)
{
s = new char[1];
memcpy(s, A.s, 2*sizeof(A.s))
}

При этом всё работает и ничего не пропадает, вот только когда программа отрабатывает и консольное окно закрывается, появляется окно с ошибкой 
"4-Lab-2.exe has triggered a breakpoint"

Укажите на мои ошибки?

Comment: Не-не, вы должны выделить больше памяти под строку, и не забыть про `n`:

    stroka::stroka(const stroka& A)
    {
        n = A.n;
        s = new char[n + 1];
        strcpy(s, A.s);
    }

Кстати, `sizeof` возвращает совсем не то, что вы думаете: размер _указателя_, а не _строки_.